# Can't use ssh with "-F" to login through a bastion host

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am trying to login to my server through a bastion host and my configuration file is like this:

```
Host 10.10.10.1 
User ec2-user
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
IdentityFile key.pem

Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
User ec2-user
IdentityFile key.pem
ForwardAgent yes
```

It works fine if I save this configuration in to ~/.ssh with name "config",which is the default configuration file of ssh. I can login with "ssh -v 10.10.10.1" and the debuglog is like:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/twer/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for 10.10.10.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W 10.10.10.1:22 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.10.10.1:22 as 'ec2-user'
...
```

But if I save the configuration somewhere else(delete the config in ~/.ssh) and login with "ssh -v -F ~/mysshconfig 10.10.10.1", It failed. the debug log is :

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data ansible-ssh.conf
debug1: ansible-ssh.conf line 1: Applying options for 10.10.10.1
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W 10.10.10.1:22 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Since I want to use ansible, I need to specify a sshconfig with this "-F" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out that I should also specify the configuration file in the ProxyCommand since it is not a default one. The configuration should be like this:

```
Host 10.10.10.1 
User ec2-user
ProxyCommand ssh ssh -F mysshconfig -W %h:%p xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
IdentityFile key.pem

Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
User ec2-user
IdentityFile key.pem
ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: If you use the `ProxyJump` directive you don't have to re-specify the config file with `-F`. However, this directive was added in `ssh` 7.3, which was released on 2016-08-01, after the date of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your config file is in a different location, the relative path to the key file no longer points to the same place, so you're getting "no such file" errors when ssh tries to read your key file.

Use an absolute path instead: change `key.pem` to `~/.ssh/key.pem`.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a path issue.I have figured it out myself.